# Javascript colorbar - best way to create it

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of colours ([created from values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182318/value-as-colour-representation)) and want to display them in a colourbar (as a legend what each colour means). Something like this.

[image: Example for a colour bar]

One way would be a table with 1 row / n columns (n = 25-100), each column representing one colour. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Use an image, way better than tables. The position of the mouse pointer hover the image will determine wich color you're dealing with.

Comment: I would need to create the image dynamically. I have the colour table, which is dynamically created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Canvas is a powerful API for this: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/eGjak/89/.

```
var cv  = document.getElementById('cv'),
    ctx = cv.getContext('2d');

for(var i = 0; i <= 255; i++) { // fill strokes
    ctx.beginPath();

    var color = 'rgb(100, ' + i + ', ' + i + ')';
    ctx.fillStyle = color;

    ctx.fillRect(i * 2, 0, 2, 50);
}

cv.onclick = function(e) {
    var x = e.offsetX, // mouse x
        y = e.offsetY, // mouse y
        p = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1),
        x = p.data; // pixel at mouse (x, y) - contains [r, g, b, a]

    alert('Color: rgb(' + x[0] + ', ' + x[1] + ', ' + x[2] + ')');
};
```

Comment: @Horst Walter: That's great, just forgot to mention that this is not supported on IE8-, which may be important to know.

Comment: Yep, is good to know, but not relevant in my use case. Thanks,